# Httpcontext shows error "Object reference not set to an instance of object "

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2013, asp.net-mvc-5

I have the following code

```
HttpContext context =  HttpContext.Current;

context.Response.Redirect("~/Views/Home/Index");
```

and its returning null exception as 
    Object reference not set to an instance of object

I am sorry this is object reference error is always a lil confusing to me. I tried to intialise the object but it still not worked.

Can anybody please helpl me on this?

Comment: Where are you using this code?

Comment: @StephenMuecke at session_end

Comment: You need to handle this using an action filter. [Refer this example](https://cbertolasio.wordpress.com/2010/11/27/using-an-actionfilter-to-redirect-to-login-when-session-expires/)

Comment: @StephenMueckei tried action filter. I faced few issues there and come up with an easy solution. But still here cant we initialise the httpcontextobject?

Comment: An _"easy solution"_ that does not (and cannot) work :)

Comment: @StephenMuecke In filter what i gave wasnt returning the url whenever the session is expired!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74941/discussion-between-sajna-ali-and-stephen-muecke).